# Simple SELECT, but adding JOIN returns too many rows

Tags: select, join, where-clause

The query below returns 9,817 records.  Now, I want to SELECT one more field from another table.  See the 2 lines that are commented out, where I've simply selected this additional field and added a JOIN statement to bind this new columns.  With these lines added, the query now returns 649,200 records and I can't figure out why!  I guess something is wrong with my WHERE criteria in conjunction with the JOIN statement.  Please help, thanks.

SELECT DISTINCT dbo.IMPORT_DOCUMENTS.ITEMID, BEGDOC, BATCHID

--, dbo.CATEGORY_COLLECTION_CATEGORY_RESULTS.CATEGORY_ID

FROM IMPORT_DOCUMENTS

--JOIN dbo.CATEGORY_COLLECTION_CATEGORY_RESULTS ON

dbo.CATEGORY_COLLECTION_CATEGORY_RESULTS.ITEMID = dbo.IMPORT_DOCUMENTS.ITEMID

WHERE (BATCHID LIKE 'IC0%' OR BATCHID LIKE 'LP0%')

```
AND dbo.IMPORT_DOCUMENTS.ITEMID IN

  (SELECT dbo.CATEGORY_COLLECTION_CATEGORY_RESULTS.ITEMID FROM
```

CATEGORY_COLLECTION_CATEGORY_RESULTS

```
    WHERE SCORE >= .7 AND SCORE <= .75 AND CATEGORY_ID IN(

      SELECT CATEGORY_ID FROM CATEGORY_COLLECTION_CATS WHERE COLLECTION_ID IN (11,16))

   AND Sample_Id > 0)

AND dbo.IMPORT_DOCUMENTS.ITEMID NOT IN

(SELECT ASSIGNMENT_FOLDER_DOCUMENTS.Item_Id FROM ASSIGNMENT_FOLDER_DOCUMENTS)
```

Comment: Could there be on average around 70 CATEGORY_COLLECTION_CATEGORY_RESULTS per IMPORT_DOCUMENT perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

One possible reason is because one of your tables contains data at lower level, lower than your join key. For example, there may be multiple records per item id. The same item id is repeated X number of times. I would fix the query like the below. Without data knowledge, Try running the below modified query.... If output is not what you're looking for, convert it into SELECT Within a Select...

Hope this helps....

Try this SQL: SELECT DISTINCT a.ITEMID, a.BEGDOC, a.BATCHID, b.CATEGORY_ID FROM IMPORT_DOCUMENTS a JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ITEMID FROM CATEGORY_COLLECTION_CATEGORY_RESULTS WHERE SCORE >= .7 AND SCORE <= .75 AND CATEGORY_ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT CATEGORY_ID FROM CATEGORY_COLLECTION_CATS WHERE COLLECTION_ID IN (11,16)) AND Sample_Id > 0)  B ON a.ITEMID =b.ITEMID WHERE a.(a.BATCHID LIKE 'IC0%' OR a.BATCHID LIKE 'LP0%')  AND a.ITEMID NOT IN (SELECT DIDTINCT Item_Id FROM ASSIGNMENT_FOLDER_DOCUMENTS)